# plot pandas dataframe in jupyter with voila

Tags: python, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook

The situation:
I have a jupyter notebook where I create and manipulate a DataFrame.

At a certain point I have:

```
mydf = conceptsdf['date'].groupby([conceptsdf['date'].dt.year, conceptsdf['date'].dt.month]).agg('count')
mydf.plot(kind="bar")
```

basically I aggregate occurrences per month. The plot appears correctly as expected in the notebook under the line:

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x283dc381148>
```

The Problem:
I have voila installed and when I click it all works fine but in the voila web result the plot does not appear but only the line:

```
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
```

Any ideas what to do to get the plots in voila output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited code that you posted, I'd guess you aren't using `%matplotlib widget`?

Example using pandas plot that works (see links below for demo notebook):

```py
%matplotlib widget
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
iris.plot.hist();
```

As documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and stated [here](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/understand-df-plot-in-pandas/) as, "Under the hood, pandas plots graphs with the matplotlib library." And so that approach will work with matplotlib in general.

Example working matplotlib plot in a cell from my notebook (linked below):

```
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
a = matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(np.random.randn(100, 100))
a.figure
```

I have some examples based on code I collected previously and [this discussion here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/pull/170). For the Pandas dataframe plot, go to https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila/ and click the badge next the text 'Start with the Pandas dataframe plot demo as a notebook'. After launch, you can run all the cells and then click the `Voila` button in the toolbar at the top.
For the matplotlib examples page, go to https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila/ and click the badge next the text 'Start with the matplotlib demo as a notebook'. After launch, you can run all the cells and then click the `Voila` button in the toolbar at the top.

Those notebooks and the 'Examples' referenced [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/pull/170#issuecomment-499439110) might provide a good basis for solving your issue.

Comment: You are right, I was simply using pandas plot. I will try your code.

Comment: I added a pandas dataframe plot example now.